# Steam indicator not showing anything ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, steam, indicator

I have a problem with steam that the app indicator in the unity panel doesn't show anything, where it should show my recent games, friends and settings, etc. It only shows a blank black vertical bar.
 Although everything works perfectly, i.e. launching games, playing etc., but it's just a small hitch that becomes annoying after some time. I am posting two screenshots that will make clear of what i am saying.

Here's the terminal output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzbxl.jpg

and here is the snap of the application indicator
https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7cdS.jpg

Any help would be appreciated as i have been searching for a solution for days and couldn't find one.

Comment: Silly question, not using steam, but is there anything it *should* do or show?

Comment: yes it should, because when i click the icon i get nothing other that that blank black vertical bar whereas it should show my recent games and other stuff

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was having the same problem.

I found [this](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/4795) open unity bug that has several suggestions.

For me, installing `libdbusmenu-gtk4:i386` fixed it.
Open up a terminal window, and type the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libdbusmenu-gtk4:i386
```